# Fortran performance for complex vs real variable

Tags: fortran

So, I was wondering if it is preferable to work on the real and imaginary part of the array separately instead of a complex variable for performance gain. For example,

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer,parameter :: n = 1e8
   real(kind=8),parameter :: pi = 4.0d0*atan(1.0d0)
   complex(kind=8),parameter :: i_ = (0.0d0,1.0d0)
   double complex :: s
   real(kind=8) :: th(n),sz, t1,t2, s1,s2
   integer :: i 
   sz = 2.0d0*pi/n
   do i=1,n 
      th(i) = sz*i
   enddo
   call cpu_time(t1)
   s= sum(exp(th*i_))
   call cpu_time(t2)
   print *, t2-t1 

   call cpu_time(t1)
   s1 = sum(cos(th))
   s2 =  sum(sin(th))
   call cpu_time(t2)
   print *, t2-t1 
end program test
```

And the time it takes

```
   3.7041089999999999     
   2.6299830000000002
```

So, the splited calculation does takes less time. This was a very simple calculation. But I have some long calculation and using complex variables improves the readability and does takes less lines of code. But will it sacrifice the performance of my code ? Or is it always advisable to work on the real and imaginary part separately?

Comment: Only you know whether you value development time and comfort less than execution time in your project, or not. In a huge majority of cases, development time is more expensive than CPU time. Closing as subjective.

Comment: Usually you do not have such small programms, you have a huge context and this little thing is only 1% of it, and if it takes 1.00% oder 1.02% is a not noticable difference. If you run your routine a million times per minute, than it's worth the effort to invest time in such optimization. But I try to keep code, made more complicated for the sake of performance, inside a little black box. It should not influence your overall architecture. If you want it fast - write it in Assembler, or use your GPU with massive Multiprocessing. You have to decide how far you will go.

Comment: Here you are more comparing the performance of the implementation of the Exp function compared to that of sin and cos, rather than complex compared to real. But whatever. Unless you have a really desperate need for speed write it as complex. It will be clearer. You will love yourself for this in 6 months time.

Comment: In your comparison, did you use -O2 etc? On my computer, gfortran optimized away all the calculations with -O2 because s, s1, s2 were not referenced (so giving time ~ 0). If I output them, the complex version was slightly faster with gfortran-{4.9, 8, 9} -O2. So I guess the speed comparison may depend on compiler/option/lib/cpu etc, and w/o more specific info, complex may be better for readability overall.

Comment: Let me speak up in favour of asking, and answering, this and similar questions.  The opinions of the other commentators are built on their experience, which I am confident, includes many little experiments such as yours.  You'll have noted that there are some flaws in your experiment which mean it probably doesn't measure what you think it measures.  No matter, fix those flaws and have another play around.  That way you build your own experience, and develop your own opinions on the merits and demerits of various approaches.  And in future you can criticise newbs around here too :-)

Comment: You really have to use compiler optimizations and report the exact flags you used together with the times you show. You must use optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Better to understand what kind of trick compiler can do for you. Generally it's not worth the effort to do so nowadays. Create a little script to study the CPU time of your code.

```
#!/bin/bash
src=a.f90
for fcc in gfortran ifort; do
    $fcc --version
    for flag in "-O0" "-O1" "-O2" "-O3"; do
        fexe=$fcc$flag
        echo $fcc $src -o "$fcc$flag" $flag
        $fcc $src -o $fexe $flag
        echo "run $fexe ..."
        ./$fexe
    done
done
```

You will notice the some of the CPU time may show very close to 0, as the compiler is clever enough to discard the computation that you never used. Make the change to avoid the compile optimize out your computation.

```
print *, t2-t1, s
print *, t2-t1, s1, s2
```

The result of using ifort is here, beside the speed, notice the ACCURACY, speed comes at a price:

```
ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2

ifort a.f90 -o ifort-O0 -O0
run ifort-O0 ...
   3.57999900000000      (-2.319317404797516E-009,7.034712528404704E-009)
   4.07666600000000      -2.319317404797516E-009  7.034712528404704E-009
ifort a.f90 -o ifort-O1 -O1
run ifort-O1 ...
   3.30333300000000      (-2.319317404797516E-009,7.034712528404704E-009)
   3.54666700000000      -2.319317404797516E-009  7.034712528404704E-009
ifort a.f90 -o ifort-O2 -O2
run ifort-O2 ...
   3.08000000000000      (-2.319317404797516E-009,7.034712528404704E-009)
   1.13666600000000      -6.304215927066537E-009  1.737099880017717E-009
ifort a.f90 -o ifort-O3 -O3
run ifort-O3 ...
   3.08333400000000      (-2.319317404797516E-009,7.034712528404704E-009)
   1.13666600000000      -6.304215927066537E-009  1.737099880017717E-009
sum 31.999 3.496 0:35.82 99.0% 0
```

you may wonder what happens between -O1 and -O2 flag, if check the compiled object file, the actual internal function it linked has changed from:

```
         U cexp
         U cos
         U sin
```

to :

```
         U __svml_cos2
         U __svml_sin2
         U cexp
```

svml stand for short vector math library. Some trade off between speed and accuracy can be found in [Intel IPP Library Fixed-Accuracy Arithmetic Functions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-fixed-accuracy-arithmetic-functions)